# Trouble Understanding Logical expression in C programming

Tags: c

I am learning C on my own and following a book with exercises that do not have answers. I am having trouble understanding why the below expression evaluates to "true" or "1" when running it in my compiler. I understand precedence, associativity, and how logical operators work, but the `a +=` trips me up. I don't know how that relates to true and false. I appreciate any help or explanation as to how this evaluates to true.

```
 int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

 a += !b && c == ! 5;
```

Comment: While a solution to this specific question will help you, a general and simple way to get your compiler to help you see what is going on is to break the expression down into smaller parts and print their value. Then start combining these smaller parts and print the result, until you see the result from the complete expression.

Comment: All of the junk to the right of the `+=` operator evaluates to `0`.  So the assignment expression is equivalent to `a += 0;`.  The old value of `a` is `1`, so the new value of `a` remains `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a += !b && c == ! 5
```

parses as

```
a += ((!b) && (c == (! 5)))
```

We can evaluate each sub-expression in turn:

- `b` is `2`.
- `!b` is `0` (because `!` turns all non-zero values into zero, and zero into one).
- `0 && ...` does not evaluate its right-hand side but returns `0` immediately.
- `a += 0` is equivalent to `a = a + 0`, which doesn't change the value of `a`, but returns its new value (same as the old value in this case), `1`.
- `1` is not zero, so it's true.

In case this is what's tripping you up: The assignment operators are, well, operators. The have an effect (assigning a value to a variable), but they also have a result. For all assignment operators the result is the value being assigned:

```
int n = 2;
printf("%d\n", n += 3);
```

outputs `5` and also sets `n` to `5`.

Just for completeness, `c == (!5)` would have evaluated as follows:

- `!5` is `0`.
- `c == 0` is `0` (because `c` is `3` and `==` returns `1` for true and `0` for false).

Comment: Even if `a` was `0` initially, wouldn't the result be still `true` since `a = 0` would just be an *assignment*, not a *comparison*?

Comment: @CinCout The result of `a = 0` is the value being assigned, which is `0`, so it's false.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `a += !b && c == ! 5;` is equivalent to `a = a + (!b && c == ! 5);`.
Hope that helps, and I hope that you never face such an expression in practice.